# build nodejs with yocto in branch Dunfell

Tags: node.js, yocto

I'm trying to build nodejs with Yocto on a 32-bit Ubuntu 16.04 host, but the link operation failed with the following message

```
/home/dev/Projet/yocto-dunfell/build/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/nodejs/12.21.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld:
failed to set dynamic section sizes: memory exhausted
```

My virtual machine has 13 GB of RAM and I've set in my local.conf

```
BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "1"
PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 1"
```

Comment: Try removing the optimization flag, remove `-O` from the Makefile of nodejs. Also try adding `LDFLAGS=--no-keep-memory`

Comment: I add nodejs_%.bbappend file with the following line to compile


LDFLAGS += "-Wl,--no-keep-memory"